# Rotating a NxN matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, rotational-matrices

This is a question from Cracking the Coding Interview. The solution says that the program rotates the exterior edges, then the interior edges. However, I'm having trouble following the logic of both the for loops.

Could somebody explain the logic of the code (e.g. why they do "layer < n/2" and the four steps of "left -> top" and "bottom -> left" etc)? On a side note, how would one's thought process be when coming up with this during a coding interview?

> Given an image represented by an NxN matrix, where each pixel in the
>   image is 4 bytes, write a method to rotate the image by 90 degrees.
>   Can you do this in place?

```
public static void rotate(int[][] matrix, int n) {
    for (int layer = 0; layer < n / 2; ++layer) {
        int first = layer;
        int last = n - 1 - layer;
        for(int i = first; i < last; ++i) {
            int offset = i - first;
            int top = matrix[first][i]; // save top

            // left -> top
            matrix[first][i] = matrix[last-offset][first];          

            // bottom -> left
            matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix[last][last - offset]; 

            // right -> bottom
            matrix[last][last - offset] = matrix[i][last]; 

            // top -> right
            matrix[i][last] = top; // right <- saved top
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Overview**

Consider a sample matrix could look like this:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
```

For the purposes of my explanation, ABCD is considered as row 0, EFGH is row 1, and so on. The first pixel of row 0 is A.

Also, when I talk about the outer shell, I am referring to:

```
ABCD
E  H
I  L
MNOP
```

**First let's look at the code that moves the values.**

```
    int top = matrix[first][i]; // save top
```

The first line caches the value in the top position. This refers to the position on the top row of the matrix identified by [first][i]. Eg: saving the `A`.

```
    // left -> top
    matrix[first][i] = matrix[last-offset][first];
```

The next part moves the value from the left position into the top position. Eg: taking the `M` and putting it where the `A` is.

```
    // bottom -> left
    matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix[last][last - offset];
```

The next part moves the value from the bottom position into the left position. Eg: taking the `P` and putting it where the `M` is.

```
    // right -> bottom
    matrix[last][last - offset] = matrix[i][last];
```

The next part moves the value from the right position into the bottom position. Eg: taking the `D` and putting it where the `P` is.

```
    // top -> right
    matrix[i][last] = top; // right <- saved top
```

The last part moves the value from the cache (what was the top position) into the right position. Eg: putting the `A` from the first step where the `D` is.

**Next the loops.**

The outer loop runs from row 0 to half the total number of rows. This is because when you rotate row 0, it also rotates the last row and when you rotate row 1, it also rotates the second-to-last row, and so on.

The inner loop runs from the first pixel position (or column) in the row to the last. Keep in mind that for row 0, this is from pixel 0 to the last pixel, but for row 1, this is from pixel 1 to the second-to-last pixel, since the first and last pixels are rotated as part of row 0.

So the first iteration of the outer loop makes the outer shell rotate. In other words:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
```

becomes:

```
MIEA
NFGB
OJKC
PLHD
```

See how the outer shell has rotated clockwise, but the inner core has not moved.

Then the second iteration of the outer loop causes the second row to rotate (excluding the first and last pixels) and we end up with:

```
MIEA
NJFB
OKGC
PLHD
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply within, your explanation is greatly appreciated. I apologize if this question is simplistic, but I was having trouble understanding on a larger scale what the "left," "right," "top," and "bottom" were and what a "layer" consists of. Would the left, right, top, bottom just be the corner pieces? Would each layer just be a border of the square going inwards?

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the explanation. I can't seem to understand the logic behind "int offset = i - first;" in the inner loop.

Comment: The explanation given in the book is so useless, code isn't important, understanding the logic is important. which this answer does to a good extend. The real challenge is to understand what all these terms represent and how they change in the inner for loop and in the outer for loop. Especially the offset term.

Comment: @Jason: Perfect explanation. Loved the simplicity. No assumptions.

Comment: @SaurabhPatil I have found so many mistakes in that book. I think it is an overrated, over hyped book. May be due to lack of competition.

Comment: What is the significance of the 4 bytes from the question? does 4 represent N, hence a 4 x 4 matrix? Also, does 1 pixel represent 1 cell in the matrix? If so, why does the solution from the book store ints and not 4 bytes in each cell?

Comment: Because an int is 4 bytes long. So 4 bytes can be stored in as an int.

Comment: I understand all the code what it is not clear, perhaps in the book or any of the solutions, is how to get the reasoning about finding the correct 'cell' coordinates, using all those variables on any of the solutions.

How do you reason to find row,col pair of each element to be rotated? Did you get it by trial and error or is there a logic to use those variables?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm writing this answer because even after reading the answer posted by Jason above (it's nice and did resolve a couple of questions I had) it still wasn't clear to me  what role is variable "offset" playing in this logic, so spending a couple of hours to understand this I thought to share it with everyone.

There are many variables used here and it's important to understand the significance of each one.

If you look at the variable 'first', it's useless, it's essentially the 'layer' itself, 'first' isn't modified at all in the whole logic. So I have removed 'first' variable (and it works, read ahead).

To understand how each of these values change in every iteration of the inner for loop I have printed the values of these variables. Take a look at the output and understand which values change when we move from one corner to another in the inner for loop, which values stay constant while traversing a single layer and which values change only when we change the layer.

One iteration of inner loop moves one single block.
Number of iterations needed to move a single layer will change as we go inwards. The variable 'last' does that job for us, it restricts the inner loop (restricts the inner layer & stops us from going beyond the shell, building upon the nomenclature Jason used)

**Time to study the output**.

I have used 6x6 matrix.

```
Input: 

 315 301 755 542 955 33
 943 613 233 880 945 280
 908 609 504 61 849 551
 933 251 706 707 913 917
 479 785 634 97 851 745
 472 348 104 645 17 273

--------------Starting an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =0
last =5
i =0
buffer = 315
offset = i-layer = 0
Current Status: 

 472 301 755 542 955 315
 943 613 233 880 945 280
 908 609 504 61 849 551
 933 251 706 707 913 917
 479 785 634 97 851 745
 273 348 104 645 17 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =0
last =5
i =1
buffer = 301
offset = i-layer = 1
Current Status: 

 472 479 755 542 955 315
 943 613 233 880 945 301
 908 609 504 61 849 551
 933 251 706 707 913 917
 17 785 634 97 851 745
 273 348 104 645 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =0
last =5
i =2
buffer = 755
offset = i-layer = 2
Current Status: 

 472 479 933 542 955 315
 943 613 233 880 945 301
 908 609 504 61 849 755
 645 251 706 707 913 917
 17 785 634 97 851 745
 273 348 104 551 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =0
last =5
i =3
buffer = 542
offset = i-layer = 3
Current Status: 

 472 479 933 908 955 315
 943 613 233 880 945 301
 104 609 504 61 849 755
 645 251 706 707 913 542
 17 785 634 97 851 745
 273 348 917 551 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =0
last =5
i =4
buffer = 955
offset = i-layer = 4
Current Status: 

 472 479 933 908 943 315
 348 613 233 880 945 301
 104 609 504 61 849 755
 645 251 706 707 913 542
 17 785 634 97 851 955
 273 745 917 551 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------
--------------Finished an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =1
last =4
i =1
buffer = 613
offset = i-layer = 0
Current Status: 

 472 479 933 908 943 315
 348 785 233 880 613 301
 104 609 504 61 849 755
 645 251 706 707 913 542
 17 851 634 97 945 955
 273 745 917 551 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =1
last =4
i =2
buffer = 233
offset = i-layer = 1
Current Status: 

 472 479 933 908 943 315
 348 785 251 880 613 301
 104 609 504 61 233 755
 645 97 706 707 913 542
 17 851 634 849 945 955
 273 745 917 551 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =1
last =4
i =3
buffer = 880
offset = i-layer = 2
Current Status: 

 472 479 933 908 943 315
 348 785 251 609 613 301
 104 634 504 61 233 755
 645 97 706 707 880 542
 17 851 913 849 945 955
 273 745 917 551 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------
--------------Finished an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------

--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------
layer =2
last =3
i =2
buffer = 504
offset = i-layer = 0
Current Status: 

 472 479 933 908 943 315
 348 785 251 609 613 301
 104 634 706 504 233 755
 645 97 707 61 880 542
 17 851 913 849 945 955
 273 745 917 551 280 33
--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------
--------------Finished an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------

 472 479 933 908 943 315
 348 785 251 609 613 301
 104 634 706 504 233 755
 645 97 707 61 880 542
 17 851 913 849 945 955
 273 745 917 551 280 33
```

Sorry but there is no way other than to ponder upon how the values of layer, i and offset change to understand what the heck is happening here.

**Finally the code**

Here is the code where I removed unnecessary first and added all the print statements, in case if anyone wants to play more. This code also has random matrix initialization and printing:

```
package com.crackingthecodinginterview.assignments.chap1;

public class Problem6RotateMatrix90 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[][] matrix = new int[6][6];
        initializeMatrix(matrix,6);
        System.out.println("Input: ");
        printMatrix(matrix,6);
        rotate(matrix,6);
        printMatrix(matrix,6);
    }

    public static void rotate(int[][] matrix, int n) {
        for (int layer = 0; layer < n / 2; ++layer) {
            System.out.println("\n--------------Starting an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------");

            int last = n - 1 - layer;
            for(int i = layer; i < last; ++i) {
                int offset = i - layer;
                int buffer = matrix[layer][i]; // save top
                System.out.println("\n--------------Starting an iteration of inner for loop------------------");
                System.out.println("layer ="+layer);

                System.out.println("last ="+last);
                System.out.println("i ="+i);

                System.out.println("buffer = "+buffer);
                System.out.println("offset = i-layer = "+ offset);

                // left -> top
                matrix[layer][i] = matrix[last-offset][layer];          

                // bottom -> left
                matrix[last-offset][layer] = matrix[last][last - offset]; 

                // right -> bottom
                matrix[last][last - offset] = matrix[i][last]; 

                // top -> right
                matrix[i][last] = buffer; // right <- saved top

                //print
                System.out.println("Current Status: ");
                printMatrix(matrix,6);
                System.out.println("--------------Finished an iteration of inner for loop------------------");
            }
            System.out.println("--------------Finished an iteration of OUTER FOR LOOP------------------");

        }
    }

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix,int n){
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void initializeMatrix(int[][] matrix,int n){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                matrix[i][j]=(int) (Math.random() * 1000);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just saw that there is a simpler way to write the code by refactoring "last - offset":

```java
public static void rotateInPlace90DegreesClockwise(int[][] matrix) {
    int n = matrix.length;
    int half = n / 2;

    for (int layer = 0; layer < half; layer++) {
        int first = layer;
        int last = n - 1 - layer;

        for (int i = first; i < last; i++) {
            int offset = i - first;
            int j = last - offset;
            int top = matrix[first][i]; // save top

            // left -> top
            matrix[first][i] = matrix[j][first];

            // bottom -> left
            matrix[j][first] = matrix[last][j];

            // right -> bottom
            matrix[last][j] = matrix[i][last];

            // top -> right
            matrix[i][last] = top; // right <- saved top
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this? What's the logic?

Answer (score 2):

check this solution to do it in place.

```
public void rotateMatrix(Pixel[][] matrix) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length / 2; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length - 1 - 2 * i; j++) {
            Pixel tmp = matrix[j + i][matrix.length - 1 - i];
            matrix[j + i][matrix.length - 1 - i] = matrix[i][j + i];
            matrix[i][j + i] = matrix[matrix.length - 1 - j - i][i];
            matrix[matrix.length - 1 - j - i][i] = matrix[matrix.length - 1 - i][matrix.length - 1 - j - i];
            matrix[matrix.length - 1 - i][matrix.length - 1 - j - i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in JavaScript, it swaps values between a row and a column starting from the top-right edge, going inwards until the bottom-leftmost pair is swapped.

```
function rotateMatrix(arr) {
    var n = arr.length - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            var temp = arr[i][j];

            arr[i][j] = arr[n - j][n - i]; // top row
            arr[n - j][n - i] = temp; // right column
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that code is pretty ugly and hard to read - primarily because the author didn't use very descriptive variable names. I solved that same problem using the same principles (treating the square matrix as a set of concentric squares and then rotating one at a time going from the outer square to the inner square). Here is my solution and the explanation of my thought process.

## The Code

I used C#, but the syntax is nearly identical to Java. After copy/pasting, just change `a.Length` to `a.length` and it should be syntactically correct Java.

```cs
void swap(int[][] a, int g, int h, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[g][h];
    a[g][h] = a[i][j];
    a[i][j] = temp;
}

int[][] rotateImage(int[][] a) {
    if (a.Length > 1) {
        int topRow = 0, bottomRow = a.Length - 1, leftCol = topRow, rightCol = bottomRow;

        while (topRow < bottomRow && leftCol < rightCol) {
            swap(a, topRow, leftCol, topRow, rightCol);
            swap(a, topRow, leftCol, bottomRow, leftCol);
            swap(a, bottomRow, leftCol, bottomRow, rightCol);

            for (int i = topRow + 1, j = bottomRow - 1; i < bottomRow && j > topRow; i++, j--) {
                swap(a, topRow, i, i, rightCol);
                swap(a, topRow, i, bottomRow, j);
                swap(a, topRow, i, j, leftCol);
            }

            topRow++; leftCol++;
            bottomRow--; rightCol--;
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

You may notice that I could potentially get rid of the variables `leftCol` and `rightCol` since they are kept equal to `topRow` and `bottomRow` respectfully. The reason that I don't is because I feel it makes the code easier to follow.

## The Explanation

First, note that if given a `1x1` matrix, we return the original matrix because there is only one pixel which means no rotation is necessary.

Next, imagine we are given the following `2x2` matrix:

```
1 2
3 4
```

You could rotate this matrix in three swaps. `Top Left -> Top Right`, `Top Left -> Bottom Left`, and `Top Left -> Bottom Right`.

```
4 1
2 3
```

Now imagine we are given the following `3x3` matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Note that the inner square is our old friend the `1x1` matrix. It's important to realize that all square matrices where `n > 1 && n % 2 != 0` will eventually reduce down to a `1x1` in the center. Similarly, those where `n > 1 && n % 2 == 0` will reduce down to a `2x2` in the center. We can handle both cases the same way.

Again, we will start with the corners of the outer square. We use our familiar previous three swaps: `Top Left -> Top Right`, `Top Left -> Bottom Left`, and `Top Left -> Bottom Right`.

```
7 2 1
4 5 6
9 8 3
```

Notice that the matrix is almost rotated; it's just those four pesky values in the centers of the exterior sides. But, also notice that each of those values are just one position away from the corners we rotated. If we continue our pattern of using a fixed starting point for our swaps the same way we did the corners, we could rotate the last four values like so: `Top Middle -> Right Middle`, `Top Middle -> Bottom Middle`, and `Top Middle -> Left Middle`. In terms of indices, "Top Middle" is just "Top Left" plus one. Similarly, "Right Middle" is just "Top Right" plus one. For some of the indices, it makes sense to start at the extreme large index (`n - 1`) and decrement. I refer to the smaller middle index as `i` and the larger middle index as `j`.

```
7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3
```

It takes three swaps to rotate a `2x2` matrix, six swaps to rotate a `3x3` matrix, and in general it takes `n!` swaps to rotate a `nxn` matrix. My `while` loop rotates the corners for each concentric square in the matrix (and each square is smaller than the previous square), and then my `for` loop takes care of the values in-between the corners along the edges. It continues like this until either there are no more interior squares to rotate, or the only interior square remaining is a `1x1` matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution in C#. Every `N x N` matrix will have floor `(N/2)` square cycles.

For e.g. - Both `4×4` & `5×5` will have 2 rotatable layers.

Following corner-combination identifies the positions:

```
(top,left) points to (first,first) --> 0,0
(top,right) points to (first,last) --> 0,n
(bottom,left) points to (last,first) --> n,0
(bottom,right) points to (last,last) --> n,n
```

Here's the code to rotate matrix by 90 degrees:

```java
public static void RotateMatrixBy90Degress(int[][] matrix) {
    int matrixLen = matrix.Length;
    for (int layer = 0; layer < matrixLen / 2; layer++) {
        int first = layer;
        int last = matrixLen - first - 1;

        for (int i = first; i < last; i++) {
            int offset = i - first;
            int lastMinusOffset = last - offset;
            // store variable in a temporary variable
            int top = matrix[first][i];

            // move values from left --> top
            matrix[first][i] = matrix[lastMinusOffset][first];

            // move values from bottom --> left
            matrix[lastMinusOffset][first] = matrix[last][lastMinusOffset];

            // move values from right --> bottom
            matrix[last][lastMinusOffset] = matrix[i][last];

            // move values from top  --> right
            matrix[i][last] = top;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code to generate random numbers in a matrix.

```java
public static void RotateMatrixImplementation(int len) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[len][];
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[len]; // Create inner array
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].Length; j++) {
            //generate random numbers
            matrix[i][j] = random.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(len, 3)));
        }
    }
    RotateMatrixBy90Degress(matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 100% result submission to this problem

Firstly I've broken the 2D arraylist into 1D arrayList layerwise,
Then rotated 1D matrix
then again placed into matrix form
While breaking 2D arraylist into 1D arrayList I've saved the positions of element in array
so that we can place that rotated matrix at that position

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Solution {
    static List<Integer[]> storePosition = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> rotateOneDArray(List<Integer> arr, int K) {
        int[] A = arr.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
        // write your code in Java SE 8

        int r = K % (A.length);
        int[] ans = new int[A.length];
        int y;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            y = i - r;
            if (y < 0) {
                y += A.length;
            }
            ans[y] = A[i];
        }
        return (ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.stream(ans).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getLinearMatrix(List<List<Integer>> matrix) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> linear = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int M = matrix.get(0).size();
        int N = matrix.size();
        int m = M, n = N, i, j, counter = 0;
        Integer[] pos = new Integer[2];
        while (m >= 2 && n >= 2) {
            i = counter;
            j = counter;

            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>((m + n - 2) * 2);

            while (j < M - counter) {
                list.add(matrix.get(i).get(j));
                pos = new Integer[2];
                pos[0] = i;
                pos[1] = j;
                storePosition.add(pos);
                ++j;
            }
            --j;
            ++i;
            while (i < N - counter) {
                list.add(matrix.get(i).get(j));
                pos = new Integer[2];
                pos[0] = i;
                pos[1] = j;
                storePosition.add(pos);
                ++i;
            }
            --i;
            --j;
            while (j >= counter) {
                list.add(matrix.get(i).get(j));
                pos = new Integer[2];
                pos[0] = i;
                pos[1] = j;
                storePosition.add(pos);
                --j;
            }
            ++j;
            --i;
            while (i > counter) {
                list.add(matrix.get(i).get(j));
                pos = new Integer[2];
                pos[0] = i;
                pos[1] = j;
                storePosition.add(pos);
                --i;
            }
            linear.add(list);
            ++counter;
            m -= 2;
            n -= 2;
        }
        return linear;
    }

    // Complete the matrixRotation function below.
    static void matrixRotation(List<List<Integer>> matrix, int r) {
        int m = matrix.get(0).size();
        int n = matrix.size();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> linearMat = getLinearMatrix(matrix);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> rotatedLinearMat = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for (int f = 0; f < linearMat.size(); f++) {

            rotatedLinearMat.add(f, rotateOneDArray(linearMat.get(f), r));
        }

        int p = 0;

        Integer[][] result = new Integer[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < rotatedLinearMat.size(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rotatedLinearMat.get(i).size(); ++j) {
                result[storePosition.get(p)[0]][storePosition.get(p)[1]] = rotatedLinearMat.get(i).get(j);
                ++p;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.out.print(result[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[] mnr = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");

        int m = Integer.parseInt(mnr[0]);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(mnr[1]);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(mnr[2]);

        List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();

        IntStream.range(0, m).forEach(i -> {
            try {
                matrix.add(
                        Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                                .collect(toList())
                );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });

        matrixRotation(matrix, r);

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you Will be able to turn NxN matrix for a times also you can choose the direction 1 means Clock-wise, -1 means opposite of it.
In the rotateMatrix method you Will be needed for-for loops each corner.

public class JavaApplication144 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int matrix[][] = {{56, 12, 8, 90, 40}, {87, 76, 99, 1, 32}, {34, 43, 25, 78, 6}, {39, 555, 65, 88, 3}, {44, 75, 77, 14, 10}};
    print();
}
```

here is the method:

```
static int[][] shiftingmatris(int[][] p_matris, int dırectıon) {
    int[][] tempmatris = new int[p_matris.length][p_matris[0].length];

    if (dırectıon == -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < p_matris.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p_matris[0].length; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j != p_matris[0].length - 1) {
                    tempmatris[i][j + 1] = p_matris[i][j];
                } else if (i == p_matris.length - 1 && j != 0) {
                    tempmatris[i][j - 1] = p_matris[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < p_matris.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p_matris[0].length; j++) {
                if (j == 0 && i != 0) {
                    tempmatris[i - 1][j] = p_matris[i][j];
                } else if (j == p_matris[1].length - 1 && i != p_matris.length - 1) {
                    tempmatris[i + 1][j] = p_matris[i][j];

                }
            }
        }

    } else if (dırectıon == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < p_matris.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p_matris[1].length; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
                    tempmatris[i][j - 1] = p_matris[i][j];

                } else if (i == p_matris.length - 1 && j != p_matris[0].length - 1) {
                    tempmatris[i][j + 1] = p_matris[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < p_matris.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p_matris[0].length; j++) {
                if (j == 0 && i != p_matris.length - 1) {
                    tempmatris[i + 1][j] = p_matris[i][j];
                } else if (j == p_matris[0].length - 1 && i != 0) {
                    tempmatris[i - 1][j] = p_matris[i][j];

                }
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 1; i < p_matris.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < p_matris[1].length - 1; j++) {
            tempmatris[i][j] = p_matris[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tempmatris;
}
```

}

Also you Will be needed to print the matrix. It is possible by that method:

```
public static void print(){
 Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("times of rotate: ");
    int dondurme = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("direction?");
    int dırectıon = s.nextInt();
    int matrix[][] = {{56, 12, 8, 90, 40}, {87, 76, 99, 1, 32}, {34, 43, 25, 78, 6}, {39, 555, 65, 88, 3}, {44, 75, 77, 14, 10}};
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dondurme; i++) {
        matrix = shiftingmatris(matrix, dırectıon);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Simple solution is:

```
int[][] a = { {00,01,02  }, { 10,11,12} ,{20,21,22}};
System.out.println(" lenght " + a.length);

int l = a.length;

for (int i = 0; i <l; i++) {

    for (int j = l - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.println(a[j][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not rotate the matrix. It just prints the rotated form of the matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution that works perfectly for me.

```
 private int[][] rotateMatrix(int[][] matrix)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<matrix.length-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j =i;j<matrix[0].length;j++)
            {
                if(i!=j) {
                    int temp = matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
                    matrix[j][i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
```

Comment: This transposes the matrix; it does not rotate it. Given the transposed matrix you would have to reverse each row to get the correct rotated matrix.