# Java how to rotate an image by 90 degrees?

Tags: java

```java
public void rotateImage90(){
    this.redisplayImage();

    for (int x = 0; x < this.image.length; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < this.image[0].length; y++){
            this.image[x][y] = this.image[this.image.length-1-x][y];
    }
}
```

I dont know what to do from here to rotate an image 90 degrees. Please help if u can

Comment: Think about what happens for one single pixel. And what you have to consider when rotating non-square images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating a NxN matrix in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882480/rotating-a-nxn-matrix-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  There  may be better ways using an `AffineTransForm`.  This method does not explicitly rotate the source image but rotates the target graphics context, and then writes the image to that.

- read in the source image. In this case into `buf`.
- extract the dimensions.
- create the target rotated `BufferedImage` (`output`) reversing the source dimensions and copying the image type (`JPEG, PNG, etc`).
- Now get the graphics context for the `output` image.
- Since you want to rotate about the center, translate to the target center anchors and then rotate in `radians` to `90 degrees (Math.PI/2`).
- Now get ready to write the source image (`buf`) into the rotated context of (`output`).  However, the anchors need to be retranslated to the starting position for the source file (`buf`). So translate back but reverse the width and height anchors to match the width and height of the source file.
- then draw the original image (`buf`) into the context rotated buffered image (`output`).
- And write the rotated image (`output`) to the file system

```
try {
    BufferedImage buf =
            ImageIO.read(new File("f:/sourceImage.jpg"));
    int width = buf.getWidth();
    int height = buf.getHeight();
    BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(height, width, buf.getType());
    
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)output.getGraphics();
    g2d.translate(height/2., width/2.);
    g2d.rotate(Math.PI/2);
    g2d.translate(-width/2., -height/2.);
    g2d.drawImage(buf, 0,0,width, height,null);
    ImageIO.write(output, "JPEG", new File("f:/rotatedImage.jpg"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```